# PayPal API connection error in a .NET application targeting .NET 4

Tags: .net, paypal

My .NET web application is targeting  NET 4. I am integrating the latest PayPal API in my website but this API showing bad request error.

Please provide a better solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate what the error is or provide a code example of what you are doing? It will be really hard for anyone to help you out without more context of what you are doing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I think , it is regarding TLS 1.1.  .Net 4 supports upto TLS1.1. but PayPal api needs Tls 1.2 .

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal API requires TLS 1.2 for all connections

For .Net 4.5 you can do

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

For earlier versions you can try this hack

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```